# How to Customise Photoshop File Naming Using Batch Command?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, batch-processing, save, actions

I have several thousand photos, which I am re-sizing to six different sizes and then saving all sizes as individual files.

For example, I have a photo with the filename ABC0001 and resize it six times. I am then using the convention ABC0001A, ABC0001B,... ABC0001F. The next photo will be ABC0002A, ABC0002B etc.

I have created an action to resize the pictures, but when I use it on multiple, open, images, it doesn't use the filename of the open picture to save the new images, it uses the filename I specified in the action. So, instead of getting ABC0002A, ABC0003A etc., I just get ABC0001A, repeatedly.

When I try and use the batch command, it doesn't have the naming conventions I want in the drop down menus.

Is there any way to customise either the batch command, or the action, so that the files will be saved with the suffix that I want?

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I think a similar question has been asked before. See: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/40795/controlling-save-name-when-using-action-to-batch-process-and-save

Answer (score -1):

You should save the images in 6 different folders according to their size if you haven't done that already don't change the file name in the actions. run the action for one size operation. store the output in the respective size folder. and then you can just use [advance renamer](https://www.advancedrenamer.com/) which is the best tool. I would recommend you read up on how to use list replace feature of that software make a list and feed it to the software and that's it you are done follow the process for the rest of the folders.

Comment: That is not what is being asked.

Comment: @Luciano i disagree