# Multiple save batch automation

Tags: adobe-photoshop, automation, batch-processing

I would like to know how to create multiple sizes of the same file and save them with a different Document names using Photoshop CC's **Batch Automation Command**. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [Here it was explained in this page . : ](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/40795/controlling-save-name-when-using-action-to-batch-process-and-save)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [controlling save name when using action to batch process and save](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/40795/controlling-save-name-when-using-action-to-batch-process-and-save)

Comment: @user7685914 if you find another duplicate question you can [flag it](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts).

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't want to use Batch Automation if you are creating copies from the same file. Batch automation is for multiple files as *input*. You want multiple files as *output*.

Look into Photoshop's [export options](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/export-artboards-layers.html) or even scripting.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you haven't created any actions before. There are plenty of easy tutorials online. Here is a simple one.

```
1) Open Window > Actions (it will open Action palette)
2) (Preferably create a new folder for your actions)
3) Press the New button and give your action a name. (record button will turn red).
4) Save / Export the file multiple times (each time selecting your desired format and location)

5) Close the file with Do not save option
6) Press Stop button on the action palette.
7) Open File > Automate > Batch
Choose your newly recorded action
Choose the folder of images on which you want to run the batch.

* Beware of files overwriting which you can prevent by using the same document name as it is when it asks to save the document.
```

Answer (score -1):

Search online how to install and use Photoshop/adobe scripts for all kinds of tasks... Once you get a handle on that.. There are many scripts and methods for performing the task you need.

Below on the adobe forums they faced a similar issue and a plugin developer explains his plugin and how to use it to perform the same task you require + additional options.

https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1894442

Good luck!