# How to export History in Photoshop to separate PNG files?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting

Is there a way it can be scripted so that I can export every move in history to a separate png file while drawing with a brush[image]

For example, in the image attached, every brush stroke is recorded in the history panel, if I run a script, would a script be able to export all these moves to separate pngs, after I am finished with the drawing?

Comment: Yes I believe it's possible. Do you have any experience scripting for Photoshop?

Comment: I have no prior experience, but I was looking for some guidance here if anybody could help me make the script..

Comment: I **think** all you need is an *action* not a script. I have **not** done this.. but it seems to me all you need is file > export, edit > step backward, file > export, edit > step backward, file > export, edit > step backward, etc. An Action would break (stop) when it could no longer step backward.

Comment: @Scott, true but what about file naming?

Comment: @Wolff https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/40795/controlling-save-name-when-using-action-to-batch-process-and-save -- I haven't used "export" specifically, but generally fi you *don't* assign a name or location for the save, the resulting save generates a unique file name in the same location as the original file. To be honest, I've have to try it with `export` to be certain, but I know this works for `Save As`.

Comment: @Scott, oh yeah. Then there's just the issue with how many steps back you can record and if it's enough for the certain case. If the end goal is just a gif of the the drawing being made one could simply do a screen recording.

Comment: @Scott - What I actually meant was, that EACH stroke INDEPEDENTLY gets saved to a png file of itself. For eg in the given picture, each 'brush stroke' is it's own independent PNG file.

Comment: While painting or after the fact? While painting, it's simple stroke, save, stoke, save, etc. But after the fact, you'd need each stroke on it's own layer. Even stepping back through history wont' work. History is going to be *cumulative* and include all previous strokes.

Comment: Can you please explain *why* you want a PDF for each brush stroke? What is your end goal? There might be some easier way to achieve what you want. And perhaps update your question accordingly because right now it seems that if someone could answer your question as it reads it wouldn't solve your problem.

Comment: (I meant PNG, not PDF of course)

Comment: @Wolff - The idea is, if every stroke is in its own layer, I can bring them over to After Effects where I can play around with masking to achieve a write on effect for the things that I drew..

Comment: @Scott, yep that makes sense

Comment: OK, then I think you should edit and completely rewrite the question. Right now it's an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). You are asking for a specific *solution* rather than describing the actual *problem*. Using the History panel won't solve your problem for the reason @Scott described. I and others might have some ideas to help, but answers won't fit the question as it is right now.

Comment: Do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the CC BY-SA 4.0 license for as long as it sees fit to do so. For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the initial idea of @Scott, you can do it using a script and an action.
The Script is not mine. I just change it to save in png. The original save in tiff.

[image]

Open the script file and edit the output folder:

This line: "var folderPath = Folder("D:\Temp");"

Put the script file in the Scripts folder.

C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop 2021\Presets\Scripts\Photoshop
AddNumberPng.jsx

Create an action with - history panel>menu>step forward, and File>scripts>AddNumberPng

[image]

You must draw in a transparent layer with no background layer if you want the transparency to be preserved.
Assing a shortcut to that Action. In my test, I assigned the F2 key.
Now go to the history state before the state you want it to save the first png and hit F2 then keep hitting it until you finish all the history states.

[image]

**More:** In additional to @Wolff's comment.

If the real wish is to save every separated Layer to png's, you can record the action just for the Script.
Then you can use Alt+leftclick the layer eye icon to hide all the other layers and hit F2(to play the action). Repeat it to all layers.

**About the code:** My teacher said it is better you write it instead of copy/paste it. This way we can understand what is going on. But if someone really wants this code in text, I can provide it later.

[image]

As I`m not a bad person, here is the clean code:

```
    #target photoshop  
app.bringToFront();  //Leó 22/02/2018 tiff to png exporting extension changed.
main();  
function main(){  
if(!documents.length) return;  

var folderPath = Folder("D:\Temp");         //You can change this directory
if(!folderPath.exists) {  
    alert("Output folder does not exist!");  
    return;  
    }  

var fileName  = "filename";     //You can change the filename here
var fileType = "png";                                        
var fileList = new Array();  
var newNumber=0;  
var saveFile='';  
fileList = folderPath.getFiles((fileName + "*." + fileType));  
fileList.sort().reverse();  
if(fileList.length == 0){  
saveFile=File(folderPath + "/" + fileName + "0001." +fileType);  
 
activeDocument.saveAs(saveFile, SaveDocumentType.PNG, true, Extension.LOWERCASE);   
}else{  
    newNumber  = Number(fileList[0].toString().replace(/\....$/,'').match(/\d+$/)) +1;  
    saveFile=File(folderPath + "/" + fileName + zeroPad(newNumber, 4) + "." +fileType);  
activeDocument.saveAs(saveFile, SaveDocumentType.PNG, true, Extension.LOWERCASE);           }  
};  
function zeroPad(n, s) {   
   n = n.toString();   
   while (n.length < s)  n = '0' + n;   
   return n;   
};
```

Comment: Err why is the script a screencapture?

Comment: @joojaa, reminds me of old computer magazines from the 80s which had page after page of code you had to enter manually. 

Comment: I'm sure the script works and answers the question as it stands. But if you read the comments below the answer, the OP seems to want "every stroke is in its own layer". Not the accumulated strokes. This might be an XY problem. The OP never edited the question though, so I guess this answers what was asked initially.

Comment: @LeoNas - this is some amazing work! Thank you so much. This is suitable for the work I am doing. And, this is kind of helpful in comparison to saving each stroke in it's own layer I suppose.

Comment: @Wolff - Yes, this solves my query and works for what I wanted to achieve! I really appreciate your inputs on this